# Performance issue with getInt within ResultSetExtractor

Tags: java, mysql, performance, spring, jdbc

I have a performance issue with calling getInt inside a ResultSetExtractor. GetInt is called 20000 times. One call cost 0.15 ms, the overall cost is 24 seconds, while running inside the profiler. The execution of the SQL statements takes around 8 seconds (access over Primary-Key). I use the mysql driver version 5.1.13, mysql server 5.1.44 and spring-jdbc-3.1.1 
Have you an idea to improve the performance?

```
    mut.getMutEffect()[0]=(rs.getInt("leffect_a") != 0);
    mut.getMutEffect()[1]=(rs.getInt("leffect_c") != 0);
    ...
    mut.getMutEffect()[19]=(rs.getInt("leffect_y") != 0);
    mut.getMutReliability()[0]=rs.getInt("lreliability_a");
    ...
    mut.getMutReliability()[19]=rs.getInt("lreliability_y");
```

My scheme looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE mutation (
 ...
 leffect_a BIT NOT NULL,
 lreliability_a TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 ...
 leffect_y BIT NOT NULL,
 lreliability_y TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 ...
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Edit: Within getInt the methode getIntWithOverflowCheck is called which seems to be expensive. Is it possible to turn of this checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

- Set fetch size to a fairly large number: [Statement.setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29). This should reduce the round-trips to the database server while processing the resultset.
- Ensure the select statement is optimal by profiling
- General table optimization, e.g. are you using correct datatypes? It looks like you could change the leffect_a to a BOOLEAN
- Make sure you aren't returning any unnecessary columns in your SELECT statement.
- Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)
- Avoid scrollable and updatable resultsets (neither are the default)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Store the result of `getMutEffect()` and `getMutReliability()` in local variables as they are used repeatedly. The hotspot jit might inline and remove the duplicate expressions but I think its clearer to not rely on this.
2. It might be faster to retrieve the values of the ResultSet using their indizes instead of the column names. You could even create a local map of names to index, strangely for some jdbc drivers this is faster than letting ResultSet do the mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The profiler shows that it's cheap to map the column name to the index. And there is also no performance issue on accessing getMutEffect.